# How to have a span/div floating over a border in an email

Tags: html, css, email

I'm trying to follow a mockup for an email that has a border with an oval filled with text that is positioned over the broder

[image: Example]

But since this is for an email, I cannot use `position: absolute` for the span that is for the oval. I also tried using a `margin-top` with a negative value but that also appears to be ignored by gmail.

Any way I can make something like this with a table layout?

Answer (score 1):

`fieldset` + `legend` is the only thing that I can think about if you cant use pseudo-elements:

```html
<fieldset style="min-height: 50px; border: 5px solid blue; border-radius: 5px;"">
<legend style="background-color: blue; color: white; padding: 2px 10px; border-radius: 5px;">Content</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This works really well... except for Outlook of course, because outlook is a nightmare to work with. I can use conditional MSO only comments in my code like ```<!--[if mso]>``` but I don't know how to get a similar layout using outlook specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, [`position:absolute`](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-position/) and [`negative margins`](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-margin/#margin-cite-note-1) are not very well supported in email clients. But you can try the [Faux Absolute Position](https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/faux-absolute-position) technique. The technique consists in using `max-height` to get an element to take no vertical space, and then inside this element place your content accordingly.

In your case, if you want an element to overlap, you will need to set a `max-height` of half your overlapping element's height. So if your element is 40px tall, you will use a `max-height:20px`.

```html
<div style="max-width:760px;">
    <div style="max-height:20px; margin-left:20px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:#ddaa3c; border-radius:20px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:8px 16px;"><p style="margin:0; color:#fff; font:16px/24px sans-serif;">Content</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" role="presentation">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:20px; border-radius:6px; border:6px solid #ddaa3c;">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni animi dolorum voluptatibus molestias eos error, ea quo quaerat, ab repellendus nesciunt praesentium nostrum quam numquam. Quo unde nihil exercitationem esse?
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You can look at [renders across email clients on Email on Acid here](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/jwd3tEzAVdzfsWSkWkAlP1pBRIhADRW36QvYo3LUkBE4j/list). If you want to go one step further and support *The Outlooks* on Windows, you'll need to use VML. I recommend reading the article linked above for this as well as [this other article](https://medium.com/@sayo1337/overlay-email-absolute-positioning-efd2f2f09ed4).